# Clip angles of MKPolyline

Tags: ios, mkpolyline

I've currently got `MKAnnoations` with a circle image on them, displayed on an `MKMapView`. When I place down a `MKPolyline` the lines meet in the middle of the circle and then leave it. Is it possible to clip the ends of `MKPolyline`s so that the lines just touch the edge of the circle, rather than going to the centre of the annoation?

Cheers,
SebOH

[image]
**P.S:** I can't just put a white circle over it as the line is over a `MKMapView` that is unblockable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`MKPathOverlayRenderer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayPathRenderer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKOverlayPathRenderer/path) might be your best bet.

Using a CGPath, I believe you get a little bit more control over the shape than using MKAnnotations, and there are lots of references on how to subtract one path from another using CoreGraphics.

1. Draw your lines into the overlay's CGContext.
2. Mask the circles and/or erase the lines under the circles
3. Draw your circles (or add them as MKAnnotations if you need them interactable?)

HTH

Comment: Cheers for that. I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to this sought of stuff. Would you be able to provide a small amount of code just so I can get the gist of CGPath and continue from there? Cheers Again.

Answer (score 0):

The best possible way is to place a white circle with red border instead of transparent circle.

Comment: I don't think you red my question properly @Adeel Ur Rehman, I noted: "P.S: I can't just put a white circle over it as the line is over a MKMapView that is unblockable"